# How to skip first n rows when using vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I'm using vectorization to perform calculation on a pandas dataframe. My calculation uses values from a certain number of previous rows. Currently it returns with error:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Because for the first n rows, there is not enough previous rows to perform the calculation.

I see two solutions:

1. For each row, check if there is enough previous rows to perform the calculation
2. Start my calculation after the nth row

I'm not sure solution 1. is possible when doing vectorization. What about solution 2.? Is there a way to tell the system to perform my calculation only starting at row n+1 instead of row 0 (:) ?

Currently my code is:

```
df.iloc[:, 7] = df.iloc[:, 6] -  df[df.My_TS <= df.iloc[:, 5]-Time_gap].iloc[len(df[df.My_TS <= df.iloc[:, 5]-Time_gap])-1].Total_run_sum
```

Edit: above I wrote "My calculation uses values from a certain number of previous rows". I wanted to say: My calculation uses a value from one of the previous rows. The one that has been recorded a certain time before current row.

Edit 2: my code above is not very "clean", I use different notations to point to the same column. df.iloc[:, 5] is the same as df.My_TS and df.iloc[:, 6] is the same as df.Total_run_sum. Sorry for this.

Comment: As an aside, I would really recommend using `[ ]` for column access instead of the dot/attribute style.

Comment: What is `len(df[df.My_TS <= df.iloc[:, 5]-Time_gap])` supposed to be doing, taking the length of a series or a dataframe?

Comment: Yes. The condition is often True for more than 1 row at a time, but I just need to return the value for the last row sorted on the index.

Comment: Hugues: then just use `.last()` or `.last(1)`

Answer (score 0):

To test the code I used the following DataFrame:

```
   Total_run_sum   c1   c2   c3      My_TS         c5  c6  c7
0            100  c1a  c2a  c3a 2019-02-20 2019-02-20  10   0
1            200  c1b  c2b  c3b 2019-02-21 2019-02-22  12   0
2            300  c1c  c2c  c3c 2019-02-21 2019-02-23  14   0
3            400  c1d  c2d  c3d 2019-02-22 2019-02-25  16   0
```

For readability I decided not to use *iloc*.
Instead, this DataFrame contains named columns as can be seen above.
Columns *My_TS* and *c5* are of *datetime* type.

I defined *Time_gap* as:

```
Time_gap = pd.Timedelta('2D')
```

Let's start from a non-vectorized counterpart of your expression.
It can be written as a function to be applied to each row:

```
def fn(row):
    wrk = df[df.My_TS <= row.c5 - Time_gap]  # Rows meeting the criterion
    return row.c6 - wrk.iloc[-1].Total_run_sum
```

But this function can **not** be applied to all rows.
The reason is that for row with `c5 == 2019-02-20` there is no row
meeting condition `df.My_TS <= row.c5 - Time_gap`.

This is why *wrk* DataFrame generated for this row is empty and an attempt
to retrieve its last row will throw an exception. You can check it running:

```
row = df.iloc[0]
fn(row)
```

So we must limit the set of "possible" rows to those meeting condition:

```
df.My_TS.min() <= df.c5 - Time_gap
```

To do it, define the mask:

```
mask = df.My_TS.min() <= df.c5 - Time_gap
```

And the masked DataFrame is:

```
df2 = df[mask]
```

Then you can run the vectorized version of code as:

```
df.c7 = df2.c6 - df2[df2.My_TS <= df2.c5 - Time_gap].iloc[-1].Total_run_sum
```

Note that:

- At the right hand side only *df2* is used.
- The result is substituted under *df.c7*.
- "Missing" values in *df.c7* are set to *NaN*.

The result (*df* after running the above code) is:

```
   Total_run_sum   c1   c2   c3      My_TS         c5  c6     c7
0            100  c1a  c2a  c3a 2019-02-20 2019-02-20  10    NaN
1            200  c1b  c2b  c3b 2019-02-21 2019-02-22  12 -388.0
2            300  c1c  c2c  c3c 2019-02-21 2019-02-23  14 -386.0
3            400  c1d  c2d  c3d 2019-02-22 2019-02-25  16 -384.0
```

## Answers to questions in the comment as of 20:09:11Z

1. *c5* is my "replacer" for *df.iloc[:, 5]*. Other columns - the same.
   Some columns have assigned names in your code, so I allocated them some
   places among the columns.
2. Your code sample contains *df.My_TS <= df.iloc[:, 5]*. So it is obvious
   to me that both of them (and also *Time_gap*) should be of the same type.
   For me it was clear that they should have something in common with time,
   so I defined them as *datetime*.
3. *c6* is another "replacer", this time for *df.iloc[:, 6]*.

Comment: I'm quite amazed at the level of details you put into that, thanks a lot ! I do not understand fully yet, please allow me some questions: (1) what is c5 and when/how is it calculated ? I don't have this colum (2) why is c5 offset into the future compared to My_TS ? I would have expected an offset in the past. (3)  What is c6 ? I don't have this column. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Ok, I think I have confused you with my initial code df.My_TS <= df.iloc[:, 5]-Time_gap. My_TS (which is a unix time stamp in milliseconds) is in my fifth column, so it's the same as df.iloc[:, 5], they are the same, I do not have a second column with time stamp. Sorry for this, i'm still a beginner. Same thing for column 6, it's the same as Total_run_sum. really sorry for this. Basically I have a time series, i need to look in the row, say, 60 seconds before current row for a certain value (Total_run_sum) and substract it from current row's Total_run_sum, and write the difference in column 7.

Comment: Your mask idea is quite good, I'm implementing it. But my condition is always FALSE, so it returns an empty dataframe. Trying to solve this.